# This may be a "Tom Swift" story, I need your help

Tags: story-identification, space, tom-swift

I've been remembering the name Tom Swift from countless upon countless of books I read as a young boy (80s).

I've googled the name and found two main sites: [Τοm Swift Jr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Swift_Jr) and [List of Tom Swift Books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tom_Swift_books) . To my surprise there is even a Jr. and Sr. series.

The scene I remember and I need your help confirming the identify of the hero in question.

There was some sort of asteroid or he was out in a spacecraft. Something happened and either the asteroid or part of his spacecraft was damaged. This damage hit a station nearby, causing havoc. The rescue crew trying to seal the windows broken were sucked into space. Due to our hero wearing his magnetic suction boots he was able to stay fixed with the station and were able to apply the rescue material to fit in the 6-sided (hexagon) hole in the window.
- Some long description of the properties of hexagon shaped structures.
- The rescue material may be expanding to fit the hole in the window.
There may be some sort of air issue too. Fitting through the airlock on a tight timeschedule, almost out of air.

I remember it as Tom Swift, yet the google didn't ring a bell. Can you help me?

Comment: [This](http://www.tomswift.net/) may help. The third series was primarily space based.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes - "A mysterious explosion on Tom's ship" and the part about a space race sort of thing. Would you care to leave an answer, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the first book in the the third Tom Swift series, [**The City in the Stars** (1981)](http://www.tomswift.net/ts3.htm),

[image: The City in the Stars]

From the [Tom Swift Unofficial Homepage](http://tomswift.net/index.html),

> The mysterious explosion of Tom's new spaceship forces him and his buddy Ben to investigate Dr. Hans Grotz, a respected scientist and director of New America, a fantastic orbiting space colony.
>
> At the same time, Tom is testing his recent invention, a high-powered engine that will launch the Daniel Boone, Swift Enterprises latest spacecraft. Someone is sabotaging the test engine, endangering hundreds of lives. Who is bent on destroying Swift Enterprises?
>
> Tom and his new-found allies, Anita Thorwald and Benjamin Franklin Walking Eagle, battle sinister forces in this cosmic adventure.